# Ansible logic to query DNS but fall back to IP address if no DNS entry found?

Tags: ansible, dns

Ansible logic to query DNS but fall back to IP address if no DNS entry found?

I have a small ansible playbook that captures facts and dumps to a file see below:

```
---
- hosts: Configuration
  gather_facts: yes
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Gather Facts
      setup:

    - name: Capture Facts
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
      copy:
        content: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] | to_nice_json }}"
        dest: /tmp/Capture-{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}.json
```

Hosts 'Configuration' is just what we provisioning at any give time.

But I would prefer if I could use the DNS name as part of the capture file name if it exists.  Given our provisioning, there are times when provisioning takes place before DNS is updated in our environment, such as for lab work, etc.

In ansible, maybe do a lookup( dig, ansible_default_ipv4.address)?  But being new to ansible not sure how to create a conditional check if the lookup is empty?  Then default to ip address?

Comment: Are you adding reverse DNS pointer to your records? Since resolving an IP to a DNS would need it.

Comment: Since you are gathering facts is `ansible_hostname` not the same as the dns name? Or `ansible_fqdn`

Comment: At least in my testing, if DNS record does not exist then ansible_fqdn is incorrect, not defined.  Whereas ansible_hostname always seems to be the content of /etc/hostname.

Comment: Correction... ansible_fqdn is echo of hostname if not DNS record exists.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly what I was chasing, but this works...

```
- hosts: Configuration
  gather_facts: yes
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Gather Facts
      setup:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_fqdn }} : {{ ansible_hostname  }} : {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"

    - name: Capture Facts Via IP Address
      delegate_to: localhost
      #run_once: true
      copy:
        content: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] | to_nice_json }}"
        dest: /tmp/Capture-{{ ansible_hostname }}-{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}.json
      when: ansible_hostname == ansible_fqdn

    - name: Capture Facts Via FQDN
      delegate_to: localhost
      #run_once: true
      copy:
        content: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] | to_nice_json }}"
        dest: /tmp/Capture-{{ ansible_hostname }}-{{ ansible_fqdn }}.json
      when: ansible_hostname != ansible_fqdn
```

The lab environment provisioning does raw imaging for speed, so each machine, docker image, VM, etc. is a mirror image until later customized.  So if the image hostname is 'template', we will have a lot of 'template' systems in the lab post provisioning.  So the above works when DNS is pending for the lab provisioning in question.  Of course if DNS is ahead of the provisioning, ansible_fqdn should be correct.